# Database design in MySQL for Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, data-structures

I'm fairly new in setting up databases. I've started building an application and after searching Google and stackoverflow I didn't find a answer that fit my needs sufficiently.

Currently I have a User table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`password_digest` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`remember_token` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `index_users_on_email` (`email`),
KEY `index_users_on_remember_token` (`remember_token`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=34 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I need to create a Products table that links to the User table. I then need to create a Categories table, Sub-categories table, Type table, and Year table so that I can include static data that the end user will not change but will be able to sort the product data by the different categories, sub-categories, etc. (think ecommerce type). So for example in Categories might consist of (Mountain, Water, Road, etc) and Sub-categories might consist of (snowboard, ski, boat, surf, etc.). I'm not sure if I'm structuring this correctly and looking for a little help.

I was thinking in the User model of doing the following:
(Users has_many :products, dependent: :destroy)
and then in the Products table putting: (belongs_to :user). So how do I finish out the mapping? Would I then add a Categories model:(belongs_to :products), and in Products put: (has_one :category)?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you sure you want that `dependent => destroy` on the User `has_many :products` association?

Comment: Category: `has_many :products` and Product `belongs_to :category`. You don't want `has_one` in this case because that would mean that the categories table would have a product_id in it which wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Tom, to your first comment. I don't want the products to exist without users...so I think so. As far as the second comment, Thank you. This is the reason I'm asking best practices and how you'd structure it, since I don't know for sure.

Comment: Am I thinking about this wrong? Should the categories, sub-categories, etc. all be part of the products table?

Comment: It's tough to say without knowing your overall design. You've actually got a bunch of questions and issues rolled up into this post. You should break it down into bitesize pieces and post them as separate questions.